# WordPress: Having a problem in plugin uploading

Tags: wordpress

I have one problem in WordPress. I need to install SEO plugin. I see an error in dashboard, ***Update Failed*** and ask me to download a plugin in the .zip format.

**Plugin Uploading Error**

[image: Photo WordPress Plugins]

Comment: Can you try using a different browser? Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Hello @CharlieStanard i'am on chrome private network

Comment: Okay. This is likely a server issue, and not a problem with WordPress specifically. Are you able to manually copy the plugin files into the plugins directory? `wp-content/plugins`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**. Enable `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config` file.

**2**. Check your *error.log* for more details.

**3**. Disable `open_basedir` in `php.ini`.

**4**. Increase `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` in `wp-config` file or `memory_limit` in *php.ini*.

**5**. Increase `upload_max_size`, `post_max_size` and `max_execution_time` in *php.ini*.

**6**. The **500 internal server error** can be the result of a faulty plugin or two conflicting plugins. To test it rename **plugins** folder to something like **plugins_old** to deactivate all plugins at once.

**7**. Repair your WordPress core files by uploading fresh versions of **wp-admin** and **wp-includes** folders.

**8**. If none of the above points solved your problem, contact your webhost support.